# Run a server behind router

Tags: windows, nat, vps, reverse-tunnel

I own a virtual private server. I currently want to run a server on my local computer (behind a router that I don't have admin access to so I can't port forward).

Can I use the virtual private server as a tunnel or proxy for my local server so clients can access the server's services? Running the server on the remote VPS is not an option.

**In Short**: The server is actually running on my home computer, but I want my virtual private server to be the 'middleman' where clients connect to to access my local home server.

VPS: Windows Server 2008
My Local PC which I'm going to run the server on: Windows 8

If there's a software I can use for this that would be even better.

Comment: You should be able to use any VPN software that has a client you can run on your PC and a server you can run on your VPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'm entirely clear on your existing set up but you *can* bypass your router using a VPN or proxy tunnel since they generally use ports 80 or 443 which by default are available.

If you create a tunnel between the two machines, the local services on your Win 8 machine will be visible to your VPS machine.

A great tool for doing this would be [Putty](http://www.putty.org/).

---

Edit: Given that there are 3 machines now and you want to access the third through the second, a VPN between the second and third should achieve this. You can create an adapter on the second (assuming this is the server) that accepts incoming VPN connections. You would join the VPN from the third and could also join from the first.

You could also play around with [Routing Tables](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/trouble/Making-Sense-Windows-Routing-Tables.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I believe your solution is for my Virtual Private Server accessing services from my home server. What I meant was the server is actually running on my home computer, but my virtual private server is the 'middleman' where clients connect to to access my local home server. Hope that clears things up?

Comment: Yes very much so. I would specify that in the question.

Comment: 1st: My local server, 2nd: VPS, 3rd: a client. VPN I believe is for making a private connection between a few computers. This requires the client to be connected to the VPN too. Isn't there a way to do so without? As in my client connects to my VPN at a port and all the data is transferred to my home server and vice-versa.

Comment: If 2 is running a vpn server connection and 1 connects to 2, and then 3 connects to 2, all of 1's network "stuff" is accessible by 3. Think of it like plugging them all into a router/switch where 2 is essentially the router/switch.